# Setting the tax code on a Sales Order Item in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have created a script to add a Finance Charge item to my sales orders when they are edited but can't get it to set the tax Code. Also the line is not committing (because of the tax code issue?)

I have tried Internal IDs and names but am stuck

Any help?

```js
define(['N/currentRecord'],

    function(currentRecord) {

        function AddFinanceCharge() {

            try {
           
            var record = currentRecord.get();
            

  record.selectNewLine({ //add a line to a sublist
      sublistId: 'item'      //specify which sublist
  });

  record.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
      sublistId: 'item',
      fieldId: 'item',
      value: 1003  //replace with item internal id 
  });
  record.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: 'item',
      fieldId: 'quantity',
      value: 1 //replace with quantity
  });
        record.setCurrentSublistValue({
           sublistId: 'item',
           fieldId: 'taxCode',
           value: 'VAT:S-GB'
        });

  record.commitLine({  //writes the line entry into the loaded record
      sublistId: 'item'
  });


                log.debug ({
                    title: 'Success',
                    details: 'Alert displayed successfully'
                });
        
            } catch (e) {
           
                log.error ({ 
                    title: e.name,
                    details: e.message
                });           
            } 
        }
              
    return {
        pageInit: AddFinanceCharge
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only use Tax codes, not Tax Groups I believe you can create a search to find internal ids:

```
var taxitemSearchObj = search.create({
    type: "salestaxitem",
    columns: ["internalid", "country", "rate"],
    filters: [['firstFilter', 'firstComparisonOperator', firstValue]], 'and', ['anotherFilter', 'anotherComparisonOperator', anotherValue]] // i.e. ['itemid', 'is' 'VAT:S-GB'], 
  });
```

You can find available search filters in the NS record browser-
[here (2019.2 version)](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_2/script/record/salestaxitem.html)

'VAT:S-GB' might be itemid? Then:

```
var taxCodeInternalId = taxitemSearchObj.run().getRange(0,1)[0].id // If you know there is only 1 code matching the search query
record.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'taxcode', // FYI I'm not sure if capitalization matters here but I downcased the capital C
        value: taxCodeInternalId
    });
```

**Disclaimer - Does NOT work with mixed tax code / tax groups. To get that you'll need to make the search dynamic ('taxgroup' or 'salestaxitem'). Unfortunately Netsuite will overwrite your taxcode internal ID if "ENABLE TAX LOOKUP ON SALES AND PURCHASES" is selected in your tax preferences (Setup > Accounting > Tax Setup - set per nexus). If this option is *not* selected you'll need to make sure to set a tax code on *every* line item.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass internal id of the tax code if you re using **setValue**, use **SetText** instead of setValue and check.

Comment: Thanks. Have just tried that and no joy. See revised code below

        record.setCurrentSublistText({
           sublistId: 'item',
           fieldId: 'taxCode',
           text: 'VAT:S-GB',
           ignoreFieldChange: true,
      fireSlavingSync: true
        });